# Cannot print values read in from CSV file using TensorFlow

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I am trying to use TensorFlow to read in the following CSV file ("test.txt")

```
46, 37, 38
27, 23, 17
```

and then print out the contents, but nothing is being printed. The code I am using is

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["test.txt"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
record_defaults = [[0], [0], [0]]
val1, val2, val3 = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
data1 = tf.stack([val1, val2, val3])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    while True:
        try:
            data2 = sess.run([data1])
            print(data2)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (tensorflow version 1.2). How do you run it?

Comment: I have version TensorFlow 1.0.1 . I have tried running the code from within PyCharm 2017.1.2 and also from a ,py file at the Windows 7 command line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting inconsistent results because local variables have not been initialized. `tf.string_input_producer` uses an epoch counter local variable, so it may just hit the epoch limit immediately (certainly the error message could be improved here).

Try this, with an explicit epoch limit (otherwise it should loop indefinitely) and with local variables initialized:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["/tmp/test.txt"], num_epochs=1)

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
record_defaults = [[0], [0], [0]]
val1, val2, val3 = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
data1 = tf.stack([val1, val2, val3])

init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    while True:
        try:
            data2 = sess.run([data1])
            print(data2)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Comment: Solved: I updated to TenserFlow 1.2.1 and made the recommended change. Many thanks.